# How to add percentages in Javascript

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to make a slider by adding 100% to each image but can not get it done.
My main question is how to add the percentages. I tried console.log(100% + 100%) just for an example and it does not work either. Thanks for any suggestions.

```
<section class="slider">
<img class="img" id="img1" src="girl.jpg" alt="" style="left: -100%">
<img class="img" id="img2" src="sport.jpg" alt="" style="left: 200%" >
<img class="img" id="img3" src="biceps.jpg" alt="" style="left: 100%" >
<img class="img" id="img4" src="weights.jpg" alt="" style="left: 0%">
</section>
```

javascript

```
var img = document.getElementsByClassName('img');

function slide() {
for(i=0; i < img.length; i++) {
img[i].style.left += "100%";
console.log(img[i].style.left);

 }
}
```

Comment: you'll have to parse the number out of the percent string, add the new number, then concat the '%' back in ... something like `img[i].style.left = 100 + parseInt(img[i].style.left) + "%"`

Comment: The `left` property is just a string – `"100%"`. You’ll need to [parse it into a number](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/parseInt), do your math, and put the `%` sign back on.

Comment: Ok that worked..thank you

Answer (score 0):

You can't because this attribute's value is not a number (it's a text). So here's what you can do:
Try to parse the text to get only the number portion, parse it into an integer, do the math, then turn it back to a string. Something like

`let tempPercent = parseInt(img[i].style.left.replace('%', ''), 10); 
tempPercent += 100;
img[i].style.left = tempPercent+'%';`